# How to set an interface from object values avoiding string type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's sit you in context.
I am declaring a constant named COLORS:

```js
type Colors = 'BLUE_GRAY' | ...
type ColourUnit = 50 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900
type ColorsType = Record<Colors, Record<ColourUnit, string>>

export const COLORS: ColorsType = {
  BLUE_GRAY: {
    50: '#F8FAFC',
    100: '#F1F5F9',
    200: '#E2E8F0',
    300: '#CBD5E1',
    400: '#94A3B8',
    500: '#64748B',
    600: '#475569',
    700: '#334155',
    800: '#1E293B',
    900: '#0F172A'
  },

  ...
}
```

What I am trying to do is to generate an interface from all the values of the colors. In this case, the interface should be like the example under this, but obviously without typing all the colours again:

```js
type Color = '#F8FAFC' | '#F1F5F9' | ... | '#0F172A'
```

I am doing this because I want to use them in a React component like this, and only use COLORS.COLOR[COLOR_UNIT], and not pass a string or anything else:

```js
    <Container render="main" grow background={COLORS.GRAY[50]} _css={page}>
      {children}
    </Container>
```

The problem is that typescript is assigning string not the fixed values of the colors.
I am trying this approach:

```js
type Colour = typeof COLORS[keyof typeof COLORS][ColourUnit]
```

I know I can use an enum to do this, but it's not the point for this example, because I want the constant COLORS to always have X colors, and print an error when coding if anyone is missing and it's not possible to assign an interface to an enum. I know too that I can write a rest, but it's not the point.

Any solution?

If I try this, the same happens

```js
type Colour = typeof COLORS
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The problem is your annotation `const COLORS: ColorsType` throws away type information you care about.  You can't annotate it that way.  You can *check* that `COLORS` is assignable to `ColorsType` without widening.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5jZW) work for your use cases?  If so I can write up an answer (or link to an existing answer). If not, please elaborate what the issue is.

Comment: Man, that was absolutely nuts. I don't understand it very deeply but it worked. Could you explain to me what are you actually doing? I intrepret that you are typing a generic that will extend the received param to the type ColourType to not loose data and then return it?
Sorry but it was the first time that I saw that nomenclature on the left of a function. But thank you very much. I am posting the solution for everyone that search this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks yo jcalz this was answered very quickly. Read the comments for more details, but this is the code that resolves the issue:

```js
type ColourKey = keyof typeof COLORS
const Colors = <T extends Record<Colors, Record<ColourUnit, string>>>(type: T) => type
const COLORS = Colors({
  BLUE_GRAY: {
    50: '#F8FAFC',
    100: '#F1F5F9',
    200: '#E2E8F0',
    300: '#CBD5E1',
    400: '#94A3B8',
    500: '#64748B',
    600: '#475569',
    700: '#334155',
    800: '#1E293B',
    900: '#0F172A'
  },
} as const)

type Colour = typeof COLORS[ColourKey][ColourUnit]
```

Now using the type Colour I can choose between the options of the object without loosing any information.

Thanks again buddy @jcalz.